# MongDB: Referencia desde un Esquema a un documento embebido o incrustado en otro esquema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongod

Hola estimados espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.
Tengo dos colecciones:

```
    // Colección CATEGORÍA con PRODUCTO EMBEBIDO
{
    "_id": ObjectId("514d920b44ae16d201a3ff51"),
    "nombre_categoria":"Bebidas Calientes",
    "descripcion": "Esta categoría incluye bebidas calientes",
    "producto": [
            {
                "nombre":"Capucchino",
                "precio":20,
                "marca":"Nescafé",
            },
            {
                "nombre":"Mate Verde",
                "precio":10,
                "marca":"Rosedal",
            }
        ]
}


// Colección COMENTARIO
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("514d91a644ae16d201a3ff50"),
    "texto" : "Me gusta",
    "producto": ???????????????????????????????????????????????????
}
```

Lo que deseo es, desde la colección de COMENTARIO deseo hacer referencia a un PRODUCTO incrustado en CATEGORÍA; un COMENTARIO no es para la categoría sino solamente para en PRODUCTO en concreto, pero el PRODUCTO no tiene ObjectID. ¿Cómo hago para hacer esa referencia?. 
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No sería mejor incrustar los comentarios dentro del producto como otro array?

Comment: Agradecido por el comentario. En caso de incrustar los comentarios o incluso solo los ObjectId, el documento puede crecer mucho y pues eso es lo que se quiere evitar.

Comment: Mongo db no es muy bueno con las relaciones, es más lento, es por eso que se recomienda en este tipo de bases la deformalización, pero si aun así lo quieres mantener separado, puedes meter en comentario un campo llamado `categoria` el objectId de categoría y agregar un campo más que se llame `indice_producto` donde metas el indice del producto, es decir si el producto es el capuchino metes en `categoria : ObjectId("514d920b44ae16d201a3ff51"),` y en `indice_producto : 0` dado que es el producto 0 del arreglo producto

Comment: Una cosa que no logro entender es ¿porqué no tienes una colección de productos? De esa forma reduces el `array` de `productos` a sólo referencias, y la relación con comentarios la puedes hacer directamente con tu colección de productos, que al final es lo que estás buscando. Al menos es lo que yo implementaría.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.